# how to get variables defined in different file in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have two files named `tmuxA.conf` and `tmuxB.conf`.

**tmuxA.conf**

```
position='bottom'
```

**tmuxB.conf**

```
source-file ~/path/to/tmuxA.conf

set -g status-position $position
```

I can't seem make it work, I'm suspecting I have to set it globally? but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tmux` configuration file is not a shell script and does not allow for setting arbitrary variables.

Comment: aren't there any hacks or workaround to achieve this?

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan Not without resorting to using some sort of preprocessing of the configuration files to create one file from a set of files.